# Install Sphinx Search on my Virtual Private Server

Tags: debian, upstart, sphinxsearch, sphinx

I'm trying to install sphinxsearch on a Virtual Private Server that is running Debian GNU/Linux. It seems to depend on upstart-job. Here is the output I get when I try and run the installer.

```
[ps64518]$ sudo dpkg -i sphinxsearch_2.0.4-oneric_amd64.deb
Selecting previously deselected package sphinxsearch.
(Reading database ... 149083 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking sphinxsearch (from sphinxsearch_2.0.4-oneric_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sphinxsearch:
 sphinxsearch depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
dpkg: error processing sphinxsearch (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sphinxsearch
```

When I then try to install upstart sing apt-get I get the following output:

```
[ps64518]$ sudo apt-get install libnih1 libnih-dbus1 upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upstart : Conflicts: sysvinit but 2.88dsf-13.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I traced that conflict to a question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/upstart-on-debian, which seems like a pretty extreme measure to install sphinxsearch. Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone please advise me on how to install on my production server? It worked with no problems whatsoever on my Ubuntu 11.10 development laptop.

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I failed to notice that this is Debian - not Ubuntu. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Forget installing using dpkg - it's much easier to just build from source and run searchd yourself. That worked much better for me.

Comment: This is exactly how I would have answered.